# Change Color of layout using user defined method Android

Tags: android

A user defined method to change Color of the layout on the basis of button clicked. And, also keep track of what button is clicked.

Like, if a user clicks any button, then the Id of that button should be saved in some variable and then the method will be called to change the colour of a specific button.

The problem is that I know how to change the colour of a button.  It can be "user1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);"

But don't know how it can be implemented by using a function that takes a single variable...

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting lengthy description better add some code and your effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already decided which colors to use, I think the simplest way is to do `layout.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.new_color));` in the click listener of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your activoty implements View.OnClickListener.
So whenever the user click on a button, the method onClick will be called and the view that was clicked will be the argument of that method. You can call view.getId () to find out which button was clicked or you can use view.setBackground (Color.parseColor ("#999999")) to change the button background.